# How to upgrade jpackage Application without running another installer?

Tags: java, kotlin, jpackage

After a jpackage application has been installed, how can I allow my users to upgrade the application without requiring them to run the installer all over again? What options do I have to allow users to upgrade?

An ideal scenario is that the underlying jars would be swapped out at runtime, and the application would be restarted in the same process. I imagine this probably isn't possible though?

Answer (score 3):

jpackage doesn't currently support auto update although they are planning to support it in future I think.

Until then, you can use this java library:

https://github.com/threerings/getdown

Comment: I think that getdown is the alternative I would recommend. Although I had some throubles with getdown, its benefits outweight its downsides.

Comment: Alternatively, there also exists https://openwebstart.com/